# Set up Wireguard AP and SMB Server on the same Pi

Tags: networking, wifi, vpn, samba, wireguard

I have a Raspberry Pi that I'm using as a SMB server for a few months now.
I'm using raspbian without graphical interface on it.

I wanted it to be able to have a Wi-Fi Access Point that sends traffic through a Wireguard VPN, so that any device connected to the Pi Wi-fi gets tunneled. I got the wireguard configuration files, and installed wireguard on it, but when I use wg-quick up to bring the wireguard connection, the SSH disconnects and I have to reboot if I want to access it (and of course the VPN goes down again)

Current set up is a Router connected to the Ethernet Cable from the ISP with the configurations for the internet to work, then the other devices connect to the router via Wi-fi and the Raspberry Pi connects through an Ethernet Cable to the router. SMB server works via mdns configuration on the Pi, and the other devices connect to it using it's broadcasted hostname.

I haven't set up the wi-fi ap yet, but I'd like to be able to continue using the SMB server without having to connect through the AP, and I want that if the VPN goes down, all connection through the AP stops (kill switch)

I tried to find tutorials on the web, but I couldn't find a good one, and most are very technical, so, is the configuration I want possible? If so, how do I do?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ***ever*** get that setup working - not because it's impossible - but it sounds like a lot of steps. I'd suggest you think through this, delete your current question, and try to break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: *when I use wg-quick up to bring the wireguard connection, the SSH disconnects and I have to reboot* sounds like a wireguard configuration error

Comment: @JaromandaX: I think it's the VPN Killswitch that stops the connection, or because I'm connecting through mdns

Comment: A kill switch is not enabled by default (in fact, there is no such feature built into wireguard, so you might want explain how exactly you did this), making this a perfect example of what Seamus is talking about: If you *think* it is causing the problem, disable it.  If that solves the problem, you now have a much much more focussed question, rather than a potentially giant pile of issues that no one else is likely to want to touch ("I have this really great and complicated idea, but when I did everything I thought necessary, pretty much none of it works...").

Comment: You may find this useful: https://www.wireguard.com/netns/ <- Using network namespaces is probably a tidier method than a firewall based kill switch, and may provide a simpler solution to the ssh disconnect problem.  Note this is explained at the end of the whole thing ("The New Namespace Solution"), after various "classic" methods that you can probably skip or skim over.